# How To Add Different Columns With Same Name To Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

How To Add Different Columns With Same Name To Gridview in c#

Like:

```
------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------
col1  | col2  | *Tot* | col3  | col4  | *Tot*
------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------    
100   | 50    | 150   | 100   | 20    | 120
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which error did you get then? Can you add a sample of your code in which you show us where things don't go as planned?

Comment: Are you using, Asp or Forms?

Comment: You mean different column with same field ? .. or just the same header title ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have same column name instead use `HeaderText`.

If its WinForm then for displaying purpose you can specify `DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText` property, that can be same text for multiple columns.

Same can be done in ASP.Net GridView like:

```
gridview1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Tot";
```